# cast of nsinteger (aka 'int') to nsdictionary is disallowed in arc

Tags: objective-c, int, automatic-ref-counting, nsdictionary

```
-(IBAction)tapOnLikerImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    AsyncImageView *likerImageView = (AsyncImageView*)[gestureRecognizer view ];
    NSDictionary * likerdetail = [(NSDictionary*)(likerImageView.tag) retain];
    NSLog(@"frndDetDict2 %@",[(NSDictionary*)(likerImageView.tag) retain]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an integer where you should be passing an Objective C object pointer. You probably wanted to get a dictionary from an array instead.

As an aside, your retain-release calls are done improperly. The retain at `NSDictionary * likerdetail = [(NSDictionary*)(likerImageView.tag) retain];` is fine, the retain at `NSLog(@"frndDetDict2 %@",[(NSDictionary*)(likerImageView.tag) retain]);` is not.

The better way of doing it (non-ARC):

```ObjectiveC
-(IBAction)tapOnLikerImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    AsyncImageView *likerImageView = (AsyncImageView*)[gestureRecognizer view];

    NSDictionary *likerdetail = [[anArray objectAtIndex:(likerImageView.tag)] retain];

    NSLog(@"frndDetDict2 %@", likerdetail);

    [likerdetail release];
}
```

For ARC code:

```ObjectiveC
-(IBAction)tapOnLikerImage:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer {
    AsyncImageView *likerImageView = (AsyncImageView*)[gestureRecognizer view];

    NSDictionary *likerdetail = [anArray objectAtIndex:(likerImageView.tag)];

    NSLog(@"frndDetDict2 %@", likerdetail);
}
```

Note the lack of any retain and release on the ARC code: ARC automatically handles this for you.